# When use Animation in same ImageView, (ex: Alpha -> trans), remaining opacity in imageview

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-view

Please help me T_T

I am using animation in ImageView

using two animation, alpha and translation

1st alpha animation

```
    // 70%~100% alpha 1500ms 3times
    private static Animation makeAnimation3(Context context, final int image_width, final int image_height, final int parent_width, final int parent_height){
        AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation((float)0.7,1);
        alpha.setDuration(1500);
        alpha.setInterpolator(context,  R.anim.cycle_3);
        return alpha;
    }
```

2st translate animation

```
    private static Animation makeAnimation4(Context context, final int image_width, final int image_height, final int parent_width, final int parent_height){
        TranslateAnimation trans = new TranslateAnimation(0, image_width/10,0,0);
        trans.setDuration(1500);
        trans.setInterpolator(context, R.anim.cycle_6);
        return trans;
    }
```

make animation and, using alpha animation first, and next translate animation

But, in this case, when running translate animation, opacity which is changed by alpha animation is remaining......

I expected each animation do not affect each others

I used , but they didn't work well

is there any idea or keyword to solve this problem? please help me

Comment: is there any keyword or some guess please tell me anything

Comment: Please don't be so rude.

Answer (score 0):

You need setFillAfter()

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter%28boolean%29)

Comment: How do i use setFillAfter()?
What do you mean that I use setFillAfter()

Comment: In my application, both Animations property of fillAfter are false

Comment: Please read the documentation which will tell you how to use it.  setFillAfter(true).  If you don't do this, the animation will take place but then the animation target will go back to how it was before the animation.  Good luck

Comment: Hello Simon, very sorry about be rude
can i ask more question?

Comment: I think my question is not clean
I link youtube which is my problem video, can you check this video?
http://youtu.be/Bn7fhaL9PHU